# Magento 2 Category pages doesn't show page navigation (bottom nav)

Tags: magento2, category, products, navigation

I'm using Magento 2.4.3, and everything seems to work fine but the page navigation on the category pages, the one at the bottom. On the categories with more than 12 products, the number of products per page, is not showing me the "1 2 3" and so on, at the bottom of the page. At top it shows "Items 1-12 of 39", but I can't navigate to the other pages. I have already tried to reindex from putty, but still nothing..

Comment: Have you check magento log file or console log there?

Comment: I can't find anything, but looks like the pagination block isn't rendered at all, any suggestion?